# Progress HUD freezes when app returns from background - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, user-interface

I am using [M13ProgressHUD](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13ProgressSuite) to display a loader in my app. It works fine, but if I send my app to background while the loader is on, and return, the loader is frozen. Why is this happening?

[image]

I'm adding the `hud` as:

```
_hud = [[M13ProgressHUD alloc] initWithProgressView:[[M13ProgressViewRing alloc] init]];
_hud.progressViewSize = CGSizeMake(60.0, 60.0);
_hud.animationPoint = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2);
_hud.indeterminate = YES;
_hud.primaryColor = [UIColor whisperRed];
_hud.secondaryColor = [UIColor whisperRed];
((M13ProgressViewRing*)_hud.progressView).backgroundRingWidth = 2.0;
_hud.maskType = M13ProgressHUDMaskTypeSolidColor;
UIWindow *window = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window;
[window addSubview:_hud];
```

and showing it as:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Show an activity indicator
        [_hud performAction:M13ProgressViewActionNone animated:YES];
        [_hud setStatus:@"Connecting via Facebook"];
        [_hud setIndeterminate:YES];
        [_hud show:YES];
    });
```

Why is it getting frozen when app returns to foreground, even when I'm adding it on main queue?

Answer (score 1):

When iOS application goes into the background, all animations are removed from all layers. I did a quick search through the M13ProgressSuite source code. It seems the library does not react on `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notifications. So when the app goes foreground the library does not re-establish animations.

See also this [this](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13ProgressSuite/issues/17) issue on github

You can subscribe to `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notifications and react on them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Add hud view in `self.view` i look into the library and there is issue in library i think, also reported on [github](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13ProgressSuite/issues/53). I Use [MBPrgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) in most of my projects its work well for me. Anoter work around would be `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and restart the animation there.

[Detail of issue link](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13ProgressSuite/issues/17)